# Pandas row processing using apply() is very slow

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, cython

I have two DataFrames, df1 (5 million rows) & df2 (around 150 rows only). I wanted to lookup df2 and update df1 based on the data in df2. Basically I have several conditions that need to be applied on df1 in the form of a DataFrame df1. Set a flag if conditions in df2 meet in df1.

```
data1 = {'type':['1','2','3'],
         'code':['A','B','C'],
         'type_2':['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
         'num1': ['101','102', '103'],
         'num2': ['','',''],
         'p_cd':['AA', 'BB', 'CC']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'type':['1','2'],
         'code':['A','B'],
         'type_2':['', 'B1'],
         'num1': ['','102'],
         'num2': ['',''],
         'custom_expression':["p_cd=='AA'", ''],
         'delete_flag':['Y', 'Y']
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df_cols = df1.columns.tolist()

def delete_flag(row_from_outlier):
    for index, row_from_delete in  df2.iterrows():
        if row_from_delete['custom_expression'].strip():
            for col in df_cols:
                if row_from_delete['custom_expression'].find(col) != -1:
                    print(row_from_delete['custom_expression'])
                    cust_exp = row_from_delete['custom_expression'].replace(col, "row_from_outlier['"+col+"']" )
        else:
            cust_exp = '1==1'
            print(cust_exp)

        if (
                ( (not row_from_delete['type'].strip()  ) or (row_from_delete['type'] ==row_from_outlier['type'] )  )
            and ( (not row_from_delete['code'].strip()  ) or (row_from_delete['code'] == row_from_outlier['code'] )               )
            and ( (not row_from_delete['type_2'].strip()) or (row_from_delete['type_2'] == row_from_outlier['type_2'] ) )
            and ( (not row_from_delete['num1'].strip()  ) or (row_from_delete['num1'] == row_from_outlier['num1'] ) )
            and ( (not row_from_delete['num2'].strip()  ) or (row_from_delete['num2'] == row_from_outlier['num2'] ) )
            and eval(cust_exp)
        ) :
            del_flg = row_from_delete['delete_flag']
    if not 'del_flg' in locals():
        del_flg = 'N/A'
    return del_flg

df1['delete_flag'] = df1.apply(lambda row:delete_flag(row), axis=1)
```

The above code works fine when tested for a small set of data, but not fast enough to process 5 million records.

Found this [Cython, Numba and pandas.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html) recommendation that might work, but I was quite new to Python and not sure how to convert above code to use CYTHON

Comment: kindly post your expected output. iterrows and apply combo will be slower than vectorized alternatives

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations which could help you with speeding up.

You do a lot of stuff repeatedly:

**Stripping** inside of `delete_flag`:

Just do it *only once, outside of the function*, at the beginning:

```py
for col in df1.columns:
    df1[col] = df1[col].str.strip()
for col in df2.columns:
    df2[col] = df2[col].str.strip()
```

**Building `cust_exp`**:

This part of the function

```py
    ...
    for index, row_from_delete in df2.iterrows():
        if row_from_delete['custom_expression'].strip():
            for col in df_cols:
                if row_from_delete['custom_expression'].find(col) != -1:
                    cust_exp = row_from_delete['custom_expression'].replace(col, "row_from_outlier['"+col+"']" )
        else:
            cust_exp = '1==1'
    ...
```

is actually independent of the functions' argument `row_from_outlier`! So you are building identical `cust_exp`s over and over again. Which means you should do it *only once, outside of the function*. To do that you could try

```py
df2['cust_exp'] = df2.custom_expression.str.replace(
                        '|'.join(str(col) for col in df1.columns),
                        lambda m: 'row_from_outlier["' + m.group(0) + '"]',
                        regex=True
                    )
df2.cust_exp[df2.cust_exp == ''] = 'True'
```

which appends the result to `df2` (`print(df2.cust_exp)`):

```py
0    row_from_outlier["p_cd"]=='AA'
1                              True
```

To further "de-loop" the function you could do the following:

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

def delete_flag(row_from_outlier):
    scope = locals()
    ser = reduce(and_, [df2[col].isin(['', row_from_outlier[col]])
                        for col in df2.columns[:5]]
                       + [df2.cust_exp.apply(lambda s: eval(s, scope))])
    if ser.any():
        return df2.delete_flag[ser].to_list()[-1]
    return 'N/A'
```

Here I have used that this

```py
( (not row_from_delete['type'].strip()  )
  or (row_from_delete['type'] == row_from_outlier['type'] ) )
```

is equivalent to

```
row_from_delete['type'].isin(['', row_from_outlier['type']])
```

and that the operation can be done column-wise

```py
df2['type'].isin(['', row_from_outlier['type']])
```

And the `and/&`-aggreation of the columns is done by `reduce(and_, ...)`.

Last but not least a question: It seems to me that there is the potential in your code that `del_flg` gets assigned more than once, and only the last one gets used? This seems odd. Is it intended?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Timus. I did update the code as suggested and did a test run on a sample of data and still didn't see any better performance. It took 15.5 sec to process 5k records in df1 with 2 records in df2.

Comment: @SuryaKiran Thanks for the feedback. I wouldn't expect much of a difference with only 2 rows in df2 though.